# Passing hash key as parameter to print out value of hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to print out the value of the key of the hash when passed into the method as an argument.

For example count_arara(3) would result in 'adak anane'

```
def count_arara(n, h = {})
 h.each do |k, v| 
  if n == h[k]
    h[v]
   end
  end
end


count_arara(3, {

  1 => 'anane',
  2 => 'adak',
  3 =>'adak anane',
  4 =>'adak adak',
  5 =>'adak adak anane',
  6 =>'adak adak adak',
  7 =>'adak adak adak anane',
  8 =>'adak adak adak adak'

})
```

Could anyone kindly push me into the right direction without telling me the answer?

Comment: So what is `n` supposed to be in your case? Is it a hash, or a key? You need both, naturally.

Comment: I am passing n in as a hash, containing keys and values.

Comment: What about "For example count_arara(3) should result in  'adak anane'"?

Comment: count_arara(3) # -> 'adak anane'

count_arara(8) # -> 'adak adak adak adak'

Comment: I see that. But here you're passing only the key, no hash.

Comment: calling the method count_arara and passing the corresponding number in will print the value associated with it

Comment: `puts hash[3] `

Comment: "will print the value associated with it" - but how do you define the associations?

Comment: So should I define the hash inside the method?

Comment: @Benjamints: I really can't say. If that makes sense for your problem, then go ahead.

Comment: Appreciate your time.

Comment: I think you want `def count_arara(h, n)`, where `h` is the hash. That body of the method is then quite simple.

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: Thank you for your response Cary, it helped.

Comment: Could you kindly help to see why passing the argument 3 in isn't printing 'adak anane'?

Comment: The method name `count_arara` is inscrutable, but unless I'm missing something, don't you just want `def count_arara(n, h={}); h[n]; end`?

Comment: *"Could you kindly help to see why passing the argument 3 in isn't printing 'adak anane'"* because `n` will never equal `h[k]` because `h[k]` returns a value for a key and none of your values are `3` what you actually want is `if n == k then puts(v)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hash is a structure that keeps *keys* and *values* associated.

```
CODE_TO_NAME = {
  'CH' => 'SWITZERLAND',
  'DE' => 'GERMANY',
  ...
}
```

Here the country code (the two letter string) is the key to **lookup** the full country name. 'CH' is the key to 'Switzerland' and so on.

To print the long country name for a two letter code you can do:

```
puts CODE_TO_NAME['CH']
```

This will print "SWITZERLAND".

Now in your example you are looping through all key/value pairs. If the key (`3` matches the value associated with that key.

Your probably would want to do something like:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  if key == number
    puts "value: #{value}"
  end
end
```

but that is overly complicated and there is a much easier way to find the value associated with a specific key (which is what a hash is intended for):

```
puts hash[key]
```

I think this should be enough to rethink your method. Also you should probably give the method and the parameters more descriptive names.